# How to solve differences in calculating `mean`

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, pandas-groupby, mean

When calculating a `mean` in two different ways (on a dataframe and on the same pivoted dataframe) I expect the outcomes to be identical. However, they appear to differ. Am I missing something?

Here's the dataset:

```py
import pandas as pd # pandas version is 1.3.4

df = pd.read_csv(
    'https://data.rivm.nl/covid-19/COVID-19_aantallen_gemeente_per_dag.csv', 
    usecols = ['Date_of_publication', 'Municipality_code', 'Municipality_name', 'Province', 'Total_reported', 'Hospital_admission', 'Deceased'], 
    parse_dates = ['Date_of_publication'], 
    index_col = ['Date_of_publication'], 
    sep = ';'
).dropna()

df.tail()
```

[image]

I would like to calculate a mean per `Date_of_publication` of the column `Total_reported`.

**Method 1:**

`df.Total_reported.groupby(df.index).mean()`

[image]

**Method 2:**

```py
df_pivot = pd.pivot_table(
    df.reset_index(), 
    values='Total_reported', 
    index='Date_of_publication', 
    columns='Municipality_name'
)

df_pivot.mean(axis=1)
```

[image]

Comment: My best guess would be, that one of them takes `NaN` into account  and the other one doesn't e.g `[1,2,NaN]` would give a mean of `1` in one case and `1.5` in the other case. Have you any `NaN` values? And can you try `dropna()` before calculating the mean to see, if it's the case?

Comment: I suspect the differences occurs since you take the mean twice when doing a pivot. As the default `aggfunc` is `np.mean`. So you are not comparing the same results. Check it with doing `sum` instead of `mean` and you probably will get different results. So you are comparing "Appels met peren" :)

Comment: Thanks for your comment @CutePoison, but when reading the data I already dropped all NA's.

Comment: Good point. The docs (https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) here tells you that `np.mean` is the default `agg` function. But if the mean is already calculated, wouldn't it just be one datapoint thus taking the mean of that wouldn't do anything tho?

Comment: If you use `pivot` instead of `pivot_table` there is an exception that you have duplicate values, here is your difference, you first aggregate those in the second snippet, while you use the duplicates in the first.

Comment: I can confirm @mozway comment here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I cannot post a code example as a comment, I want to leverage on @mozway's answer that the reason is duplicates in the `columns` when doing a `pivot_table`

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"total":[50,10,30,15,10,5],"state":["UC","FI","DK","LM","NA","PL"]},index=["2021-11-29"]*3+["2021-11-30"]*3)
df.index.name = "date"
print(df) #No duplicated "state"

#     total  state
#date       
#2021-11-29 50  UC
#2021-11-29 10  FI
#2021-11-29 30  DK
#2021-11-30 15  LM
#2021-11-30 10  NA
#2021-11-30 5   PL

df["total"].groupby(df.index).mean()

#2021-11-29    30.0
#2021-11-30    10.0


pd.pivot_table(df.reset_index(),index="date",values="total",columns="state").mean(axis=1)

#2021-11-29    30.0
#2021-11-30    10.0
```

as seen, it gives the same result *but* when we change the `PL` to `NA` in the `state` i.e we now have 2x`NA` the result for the `pivot_table` is changed

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"total":[50,10,30,15,10,5],"state":["UC","FI","DK","LM","NA","NA"]},index=["2021-11-29"]*3+["2021-11-30"]*3) #changed the 'PL' 'NA'

#2021-11-29    30.00
#2021-11-30    11.25 #was 10.0 before
```

Comment: Thanks, that solves the issue. The dataset had two rows for municipality Amsterdam per day. After a `groupby().sum()` on date and municipality the issue was solved.